# German ß in \section and LuaLaTeX crashes

Tags: luatex

What ist wrong here? (As I use the good old german orthography the letter ß is almost everywhere and LuaLaTeX has a big problem with it.)

```
% LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[a4paper,20pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

%\MakeUppercase{Meßprozeß}% Crashes!
\MakeUppercase{Me\ss proze\ss}% Works, but I would like to write "ß"
%directly.

%\uppercase{Meßprozeß}% Crashes in LuaLaTeX, works in Plain LuaTeX (but not
%correctly: "MEßPROZEß").

%\section{Meßprozeß}% Crashes!
\section{Me\ss proze\ss}% See \MakeUppercase.

Wrong running head!

\end{document}
```

When I activate one of the commented lines LuaLaTeX does not produce any output: `! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.`

Comment: It works for me. Make sure that the example code reproduces the problem.

Comment: On my system it is exactly this code that makes the problem (Windows 10 64 bit, TeXStudio, LuaTeX 1.11.2).

Comment: Hm... I have the same LuaTeX, but on Linux. Check if the encoding of your file is utf8.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. The encoding was wrong... It is usually set to UTF8 in a new document by TeXStudio... Maybe my cats jumped onto the keyboad. :D

Comment: That indeed sounds like something cats would do ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the file was saved with a non-utf8 encoding. Switching the encoding back to utf8 solved the problem.